# PHP contact form is not sending if the user use an @yahoo domain

Tags: php, forms, email, yahoo

I just notice a problem with the contact form in our web site, is working fine with any email the user may use, but if the user use an @yahoo mail, the contact form does not send the information. Also  the contact form sends a copy to the sender, and the copy of the email reach the yahoo account.

I already tried to change the mail header, with one of my server, adding a Replay-To.(sending there the user mail) so the users can write to each other without a problem.

But again the contact form works fine with any domain except yahoo.

Please, be kind to revise my code and see if something is wrong with it.

```
<?php 

$_POST['Email'] = trim($_POST['Email']);
if($_POST['Email']=='test@ex.com'){
  //hwSessionSetVar('img_verify_skipped', 6);
  hwSessionSetVar('cInfo',$_POST['Name']."\n".$_POST['Email']."\n".$_POST['Phone']);
  die('Test Mode');
}
if($_POST['Name']=='' or $_POST['Email']=='' or $_POST['Phone']=='' or     $_POST['Message']=='' or !IsEmail($_POST['Email']))
{
echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">javascript:history.back(alert("Error: Favor de llenar todos los campos con la informacion correcta e intentarlo de nuevo"));</script>';
exit;
}
else {

require_once SITE_PATH.'modules/Captcha/class.image_verify.php';
$o_iv = new Image_Verify;
if(!$o_iv->IsTextOK(false,5)){ 
  echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">javascript:history.back(alert("'.hwLng('err_img_code').'"));</script>';
  exit;
}


//mysql_connect('localhost','alex_4email','Sys4Se') or die ('error de conexion'.mysql_error());
//mysql_select_db('alex_cl4');

$id_cc = (int)$_POST['id_cc'];
list($uid,$l_title,$l_descr,$l_price,$l_email) = $db->one_row("SELECT userid,v_title,v_descr,v_price,hw_email FROM ".TBL_AD." WHERE link_id=".$id_cc);
if(!$uid) die('Access Denied');

list($to,$cc,$en_ad_email) = $db->one_row("SELECT email,email_2,hw_en_ad_email FROM ".TBL_USER." WHERE id=".$uid);

if($en_ad_email && IsEmail($l_email)){
  $to = $l_email;
  $cc = '';
}

//DIRECCIONES DE EMAIL PARA PRUEBAS
//$to = "" ;
//$cc = ""; 
//$cc = ""; 
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ad_url = 'http://clasificadoscontacto.com/'.hwGetAdURL($id_cc);//index.php?page=out&id='.$id_cc;
if(EN_SE_ADV) hwProcessTags($ad_url);

/****************CONSTRUYE EMAIL AVISA  A CLIENTE*****************************/
$s1_to=$to; //cuenta destino
$s1_subject="Solicitud de informacion en www.clasificadoscontacto.com"; //subject
$s1_html='<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 //mensaje

//para el envo en formato HTML
//direccin del remitente

if(strpos($_REQUEST['Name'],"\n")!==false) die('Access Denied');

$s1_headers = 'From: postmaster@clasificadoscontacto.com' . "\r\n" .
          "Reply-To:".$_REQUEST['Name']." <".$_REQUEST['Email']."> \r\n";
$s1_headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$s1_headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";


/****************CONSTRUYE EMAIL CC  A CLIENTE*****************************/
        $s2_tocc=$cc; //cuenta destino

        //direccin del remitente
        $s2_headers = "From: noreply@clasificadoscontacto.com \r\n";
        $s2_headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $s2_headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

    if ($cc!="")
    {   
        mail($s2_tocc,$s1_subject,$s1_html,$s2_headers);
//hwSendMail($s2_tocc,'noreply@clasificadoscontacto.com',$s1_subject,$s1_html);
    }
/****************CONSTRUYE EMAIL PARA CLASIFICADOS CONTACTO Y PERSONA QUE CONTACTA*****************************/
    $s_contacto="ayuda@clasificadoscontacto.com"; //cuenta destino
    $s_interesado=$_REQUEST['Email']; //cuenta destino
    $s_sub_contacto="www_contacto ".$to.", ".$cc;
    $s_sub_interesado="Copia de su solicitud en clasificadoscontacto.com"; //subject
    $s3_html='<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 //mensaje
//para el envo en formato HTML

    mail($s_contacto,$s_sub_contacto,$s3_html,$s1_headers);
    //hwSendMail($s_contacto,$_REQUEST['Name']." <".$_REQUEST['Email'].">",$s_sub_contacto,$s3_html);
  mail($s_interesado,$s_sub_interesado,$s3_html,$s2_headers);
//hwSendMail($s_interesado,'noreply@clasificadoscontacto.com',$s_sub_interesado,$s3_html);

  $l_descr = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',strip_tags($l_descr)));
  $len = DESCR_MAX_LEN>0 ? DESCR_MAX_LEN : 253;
  if($len>253) $len = 253;
  if($len>0 && strlen($l_descr)>$len) $l_descr = substr($l_descr,0,$len).'..';

  $a_v = array('Email','Name','Phone','Message');
  foreach($a_v as $k) $_POST[$k] = $_POST[$k]!='' ? html_esc(trim(strip_tags($_POST[$k]))) : '';
  $db->query('INSERT INTO '.hwModTable('Form_to_Email','request').' SET lid='.$id_cc.',ts_added=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),uid='.$uid.
    ',ip=?,email=?,name=?,phone=?,msg=?,l_title=?,l_descr=?,l_price=?', 
array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],$_POST['Email'],$_POST['Name'],$_POST['Phone'],$_POST['Message'],$l_title,$l_descr,$l_price) );

/****************************************************************************/

               hwSessionSetVar('cInfo',$_POST['Name']."\n".$_POST['Email']."\n".$_POST['Phone']);

  if(mail($s1_to,$s1_subject,$s1_html,$s1_headers)){
  //if(hwSendMail($s1_to,$_REQUEST['Name']." <".$_REQUEST['Email'].">",$s1_subject,$s1_html)){
          header( "Location: index.php?page=envio_ok" );
      exit;
        }
        else{
           print "The email cannot be sent, favor de contactarte con : webmaster@clasificadoscontacto.com";
        }


}
```

So if the user use his yahoo account the script always says: the email cannot be sent.  Thanks all of you for your kind answers.

Comment: Can you strip your code down to the parts that are relevant?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: HI Diddle Dot,  I dont know what is relevant for you? i mean why all this code works fine with any domain except yahoo.? the part where the haeder is constructed is this://para el envo en formato HTML
//direccin del remitente

if(strpos($_REQUEST['Name'],"\n")!==false) die('Access Denied');

$s1_headers = 'From: postmaster@clasificadoscontacto.com' . "\r\n" .
          "Reply-To:".$_REQUEST['Name']." <".$_REQUEST['Email']."> \r\n";
$s1_headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$s1_headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

Comment: @IsraelToxqui How about any part that is validating the email, or the relevant condition that would send the code to "Email cannot be sent". The entire markup for your email, not terribly relevant. Please make edits to your question instead of hard to read comments.

Comment: Thanks Dan08,  i cleaned the HTML that was not relevant.

Comment: Hi every one i want you to know that finally the contact form is working for any domain. The problem was not the code, not yahoo, the problem was in the spam rulers on the server, somehow was blocking only yahoo.

Answer (score 1):

Hi every one i want you to know that finally the contact form is working for any domain. The problem was not the code, not yahoo, the problem was in the spam rulers on the server, somehow was blocking only yahoo. –